# Is there anyway to restore a dump.rdb redis backup file remotely?

Tags: redis

i have written some Golang code to backup a bunch of Redis clusters
the only way i have found to restore these backups is to copy the dump.rdb file in a certain directory and restart the Redis instance
the instances are docker containers and volumes are set for persistence
is there any way to restore a dump.rdb file remotely
any tools that can help?

Answer (score 0):

If loading the rdb upon container startup is not an option for you, it is possible to transform the rdb file into redis protocol and import the raw protocol.

1. Make sure you have [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) available.
2. `scp source-redis:/data/dump.rdb ./dump.rdb`
3. `rdb -c protocol dump.rdb > ./dump.protocol`
4. `scp ./dump.protocol target-redis:/data/dump.protocol`
5. `ssh target-redis -C 'redis-cli --pipe < /data/dump.protocol'`

Comment: This method does not work for cluster mode, because it does not handle the MOVED replies. You'll only get the slots for the specific host pushed.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh target-redis -C 'cat /data/dump.protocol | redis-cli --pipe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `--pipe` method does not work for Redis Cluster as a target, I wanted to add the following great toolset which is indeed able to either use the `nodes.conf` from the server or via the `rmt -m` (migrate) mode:

https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-rdb-cli